# Apache2 HTTP conf RewriteRule www.domain.com/page1 to /domain/com/www/page1?

Tags: http, mod-rewrite, apache2

I'm sorry if this is a fairly simple question, I'm setting up a test web server and I'm trying to convert it from multiple VirtualHost statements into one statement that is dynamic and can grow automatically without needing to create new VirtualHost entries every time a new website is designed.

the structure is `/domain/suffix/prefix/folder1`

for example

`www.hello.com/world1`  would go to

`/var/www/hello/com/www/world1`

`blog.world.net/world2` would go to

`/var/www/world/net/blog/world2`

Any ideas? that would be great. Cheers.

Comment: There isn't a pattern to make a rule. Unless you want a rule for each possibility, I suggest you design a format where there is a correlation between the requested URI and the substitution URI. For example: `blog.world.net` becomes `/blog`, so there is no way to guess what becomes what.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you have a Common Front Controller file (preferably index.php). This front controller file can parse and route the request params to reach appropriate module / subfolder.

Apache mod-rewrite logic will help us:

```
<VirtualHost my.domain.com:80>
    ServerName   my.domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/     
    RewriteEngine off     
    <Location />
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
        RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
        RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php [NC,L]
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```